# How to select a specific string part from a list

Tags: powershell

I have the following list:

```
$list = foreach-object {$_}

output:

CN=laura monager sevilla,OU=CADIZ,OU=ANDALUCIA,OU=provincias,DC=...,DC=local
CN=andres perez rodriguez,OU=MURCIA,OU=provincias,DC=...,DC=local
CN=antonio maullet rivera,OU=MURCIA,OU=provincias,DC=...,DC=local
CN=ibai llanos galatea,OU=MURCIA,OU=provincias,DC=...,DC=local
```

I want to select the second string separated by commas so that it shows me:
expected output:

```
OU=CADIZ
OU=MURCIA
OU=MURCIA
OU=MURCIA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [`split`](https://ss64.com/ps/split.html) the value using the comma character as the string separator since it's comma delimited. As soon as you split the string, the value becomes an array. You can tell it to show the second element of each iterated string that's split to get the expected values using the applicable index value (e.g. `[1]`).

```
$List | ForEach-Object { $_.Split(",")[1] };
```

---

## Supporting Resources

- [Split()](https://ss64.com/ps/split.html)

  > **Key**
  >
  > `strSeparator`  The character used to split up each string, by
  > default whitespace (space/newline/tab)
- [Create and use PowerShell Arrays](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-arrays.html)

  > To retrieve an element, specify its number, PowerShell automatically
  > numbers the array elements starting at 0.
  >
  > So for example, this array:
  >
  > ```
  > PS C:\> $myArray = 64,"Hello",3.5,"World", "Demo"
  > ```
  >
  > Will have the automatic index numbers:
  >
  > ```
  > +----+-------+-----+-------+------+
  > | 0  |   1   |  2  |   3   |  4   |
  > +----+-------+-----+-------+------+
  > | 64 | Hello | 3.5 | World | Demo |
  > +----+-------+-----+-------+------+
  > ```
  >
  > Think of the index number as being an offset from the staring element.
  >
  > Return all the elements in an array:
  >
  > ```
  > PS C:\> $myArray
  > ```
  >
  > Return the first element in an array:
  >
  > ```
  > PS C:\> $myArray[0]
  > 64
  > ```
  >
  > Return index #3 (which is the 4th element):
  >
  > ```
  > PS C:\> $myArray[3]
  > World
  > ```
  >
  > Return the 2nd and 4th index from the array:
  >
  > ```
  > PS C:\> $myArray[2,4]
  > 3.5 Demo
  > ```
  >
  > Return the 4th through to the 9th index from the array:
  >
  > ```
  > PS C:\> $myArray[4..9]
  > ```

Answer (score 0):

The strings are LDAP DNs, so it's more complex than just "separated by commas" as each DN component can also have backslash-escaped `\,` within it.

To correctly split a DN into components, use:

```powershell
$dn = "CN=Fred Foobar\, Jr.,OU=Staff,O=Foobar Enterprises\, Inc."

$rdns = [regex]::Matches($dn, "(?:[^\\,]|\\.)+") `
        | % {$_.Value} `
        | % {$_ -replace "\\([^0-9A-F])", "`$1" }
        # this is still not quite correct but it'll do

$cn = $rdns[0]
$ou = $rdns[1]
```

For non-DN strings where a comma is always a separator, it's simpler:

```powershell
$parts = $string -split ","

$second = $parts[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This command will return the first OU in the list/array:

```
$list | Select-String "OU=\w+" | foreach {$_.Matches.Value}
```

Here is my output on two of your lines :

```
PS> $list | Out-String
CN=laura monager sevilla,OU=CADIZ,OU=ANDALUCIA,OU=provincias
CN=andres perez rodriguez,OU=MURCIA,OU=provincias

PS> $list | Select-String "OU=\w+" | foreach {$_.Matches.Value}
OU=CADIZ
OU=MURCIA
```